# Second jquery "chunk" not running

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery below.  When the user clicks .commentCount, I want this div called #commentSec to open up, and then some other elements on the site change.  This jquery chunk runs fine.  However, the second chunk, onclick of a close button called .closeComments, doesn't run at all.  What am I doing wrong? Do I have to return true or something in the first jquery section?  Thanks--

```
 $('.commentCount').click( function() {
        $('#commentSec').css({ 'display' : 'inline', 'height' : 'auto', 'padding' : '10px', 'padding-bottom' : '0px', 'margin-bottom' : '10px', 'margin-left' : '10px', 'z-index' : '10'});
        $('#commentSec h3').css({ 'display' : 'block'});
        $('#rightcolumn').css({ 'opacity' : '.3'}); //Transparent rightcolumn
    });
```

Second Chunk:

```
$('.closeComments').click( function() {
    $('#commentSec').css({ 'display' : 'none'});
    $(this).css({'opacity' : '.9'});
    $('#rightcolumn').css({ 'opacity' : '1'}); //Undo transparent rightcolumn
});
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<h3><b>' . $useranswering . '\'s</b> ANSWER</h3><img class="closeComments" src="../Images/bigclose.png" alt="close"/>
    <span><a class="prev" >&larr; previous answer</a><a class="next" href="">next answer &rarr;</a></span>
    <div>
    <p>' . $answer . '</p>
    <form method=post>
            <input type="hidden" value="'. $ansid .'" name="answerid">
            <textarea rows="2" cols="33" name="answercomment">Comment on this answer</textarea>

            <input type="image" src="../Images/commentSubmit.png"/>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML.  Then, several things to improve: 1) use jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` instead of setting `display: none` and `display: block`.  2) Opacity is a value from 0 to 1.0.  '9' is not a legal value for opacity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery chunk not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547372/jquery-chunk-not-running)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

The third line of your Second Chunk:
    $(this).css({'opacity' : '9'});

Should that not be:
    $(this).css({'opacity' : '0'});