# jQuery chunk not running

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have the following jquery below. When the user clicks `.commentCount`, I want this div called `#commentSec` to open up, and then some other elements on the site change. This jquery chunk runs fine.

However, the second chunk, onclick of a close button called `.closeComments`, doesn't run at all. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to return true or something in the first jquery section?

```
 $('.commentCount').click( function() {
        $('#commentSec').css({ 'display' : 'inline', 'height' : 'auto', 'padding' : '10px', 'padding-bottom' : '0px', 'margin-bottom' : '10px', 'margin-left' : '10px', 'z-index' : '10'});
        $('#commentSec h3').css({ 'display' : 'block'});
        $('#rightcolumn').css({ 'opacity' : '.3'}); //Transparent rightcolumn
    });
```

Second Chunk:

```
$('.closeComments').click( function() {
    $('#commentSec').css({ 'display' : 'none'});
    $(this).css({'opacity' : '.9'});
    $('#rightcolumn').css({ 'opacity' : '1'}); //Undo transparent rightcolumn
});
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<h3><b>' . $useranswering . '\'s</b> ANSWER</h3><img class="closeComments" src="../Images/bigclose.png" alt="close"/>
    <span><a class="prev" >&larr; previous answer</a><a class="next" href="">next answer &rarr;</a></span>
    <div>
    <p>' . $answer . '</p>
    <form method=post>
            <input type="hidden" value="'. $ansid .'" name="answerid">
            <textarea rows="2" cols="33" name="answercomment">Comment on this answer</textarea>

            <input type="image" src="../Images/commentSubmit.png"/>
```

Comment: There's no particular reason why the code shouldn't run. Did you get the class name correct? Is the element being inserted later? If so, maybe use `$.live` instead.

Comment: Yep.  Looks fine to me.  What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I dunno... when one clicks on commentCount, it changes display of commentSec to block, and then when one clicks on closeComments, it is supposed to change the commentSec display to none.... but it isn't.

Comment: This is a wild guess: `.closeComments` is a child node of `.commentCount` and the click event bubbles up to the parent causing the first chunk's execution which undoes what was done in the second code block.

Comment: #commentSec is on a different php page, and in it via an include is the html code I pasted above.

Comment: @Majid i dunno, .commentCount does not have any children, it is just an image.

Comment: ahah... it has something to do with .closeComments being in a different include page inside of #commentSec I think.  Because clicking on a different page element instead of .closeComments executes perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only issue that comes to my mind is that probably you might have multiple [XX comments] links, and having multiple [commentsSec]

now, you can only have one block with one ID. here is perfectly working example:

```
<style>
    .comment { display: none;}
</style>
<div class="comment-container"><span class="open-comment">[xx comments]<
    <div class="comment">Lorem Ipsum<span class="close-comment">[close]<
</div>
<div class="comment-container"><span class="open-comment">[xx comments]<
    <div class="comment">Lorem Ipsum<span class="close-comment">[close]<
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".open-comment").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().find(".comment").show({duration: 1000});
        });
        $(".close-comment").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().hide({duration: 1000});
        });
    });
</script>
```